# Evaluating min/max probability with Geometric random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is an exercise problem that I am solving from the book *Probability and Random Processes for Electrical and Computer Engineers (Gubner, 2002)* that I'm having trouble understanding. For anyone curious, the problem is Exercise 18 from Chapter 2.

> Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent, $\text{geometric}_1(p)$ random variables. Evaluate $P(\text{min}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \gt l)$ and $P(\text{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \le l)$.

The **textbook solution** is as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{min}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \gt l) & = P\left( \bigcap_{k = 1}^n \{X_k \gt l\} \right) \\\
& = \prod_{k = 1}^n P(X_k \gt l) \\\
& = \prod_{k = 1}^n p^l \\\
& = p^{ln} \end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{max}(X_1,\dots,X_n) \le l) & = P\left( \bigcap_{k = 1}^n \{X_k \le l\} \right) \\\
& = \prod_{k = 1}^n P(X_k \le l) \\\
& = \prod_{k = 1}^n (1 - p)^l \\\
& = (1 - p^l)^n \end{align}
$$

I'm having trouble understanding pretty much the entire solution. If I were to summarize what's particularly puzzling me:

1. How was the first line of each solution derived (i.e. $P(\text{min}(X_1, \dots, X_n \gt l) = P(\cap_{k = 1}^n \{X_k \gt l \}) $ and the corresponding equation for $\text{max}$)?
2. The PMF for $\text{Geometric}_1(p)$ is given as $p_X(k) = (1 - p)p^{k - 1}$. How is $P(X_k \gt l) = p^l$? The same applies for the $\text{max}$ case as well.

Comment: If the smallest of $n$ numbers is greater than $l$ than each number must be greater than $l$—otherwise the smallest could not be! Applied to RVs and in set notation $\{X>l\}=\cap_{k=1}^n \{X_k>l\}$  where $X=\min\{X_1,\dotsc, X_n\}$. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This is because **the *minimum* of a set of numbers is greater than $l$ if and only if *all* the numbers are greater than $l$**. So $\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)>l$ if and only if $X_1 > l$ and $X_2 > l$ and ... and $X_n > l$. Note that the event "$X_1 > l$ and $X_2 > l$ and ... and $X_n > l$" is written as $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{n}\{ X_k > l\}$. Thus $$P(\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n) > l) = P\left(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{n}\{ X_k > l\}\right).$$

The $\max$ case is similar reasoning; it's because **the *maximum* of a set of numbers is less than or equal to $l$ if and only if *all* the numbers are less than or equal to $l$**.

Note that what I said above holds true regardless of the distribution of the $X_k$'s.

2) Note that if $X$ has PMF $(1-p)p^{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$, then for any integer $l\ge 1$, we have
$\begin{align*}P(X \le l) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{l} P(X=k) \\ &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{l}  (1-p)p^{k-1} \\ &= (1-p)\times \frac{1-p^{l}}{1-p} \quad(\text{using the }\textbf{geometric series formula})\\ &= 1-p^l.\end{align*}$

(And so $P(X > l) = 1-P(X\le l) = p^l$.)